# How To Place Google AdSence code externally

Tags: javascript, adsense

I was looking to setup Google AdSence to monetize my multi-page site, and was wondering if would be ok if I placed the script externally so I can easily edit it and delete it on all pages if necessary.

The code I would but in the location I want the ad:

```
<script src=”ad-1.js”></script>
```

And I would copy the AdSence code (Minus the < Script > tags) into the “ad-1.js” file.

Would this be breaking any AdSence rules? Also, is there any way to avoid Ad blockers from blocking the ads?

Edit: I signed up for AdSence, and searching the docs and Google finds me no additional information. Does anyone know if this violates any rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found an answer, and posting it here for others that may come across this question.

You can use the jQuery "Get Script" command, like this:

In the HTML file:

```
//Calls jQuery
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
//Calls external js file
    <script src="/header.js"></script>
```

header.js:

```
$.getScript( "LINK TO CALL GOOGLE ADS" )
ANY ADDITIONAL CODE THAT GOES INSTIDE THE <SCRIPT> TAG GOES HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

How exactly `ad-1.js` will look like? Note that the tag is `<ins>` element with a `<script>` tag. You can't just put `<ins>` element in `ad-1.js` file as `<ins>` is HTML and and you can put only JS code in the JS file. You would need to put something like:

```
document.write('<ins class="adsbygoogle" ...');
```

But generally using blocking scripts in HTML is discouraged as it prevents browser from efficiently parsing and evaluating the page. If your goal is to be able to disable ads with one change - I'd suggest instead puttin `<ins>` tags and then, when you need to disable ads, you can add `.adsbygoogle { display: none; }` style to some common CSS file used across all your pages. That will effectively prevent ads from loading.

Answering some of your questions:

> Would this be breaking any AdSence rules?

No, it doesn't break rules. You can place `<ins>` tags from JS.

> Also, is there any way to avoid Ad blockers from blocking the ads?

AdSense doesn't provide feature for that. There probably some libraries that can help you detect whether user has adblock installed and do something based on that. For example show some banner asking user to disable adblocker.

Comment: I was thinking more like this: https://www.webmasterworld.com/forum89/818.htm      As for ad blocking, I meant if there was a way to show the ads even if an adbloker was detected (So don't show a message, just somehow avoid the blocker and show the ads anyway)

Comment: The thread you mention is pretty old (2003) and uses the legacy version of AdSense tag - `show_ads.js`. The modern tag is `adsbygoogle.js`. For the ad blockers - no, there is no normal way to circumvent them.

Comment: I know it is pretty old, that is one of the reasons I came here to ask about it. Would something like that work where I have a <script src=”google-ad.js”></script> wherever I want an ad, and the code that Google provides inside that file?